# click command line within conda environment- mac m1 chip

Tags: python, tensorflow, apple-m1

I am currently working with tensorflow on a new mac with M1 chip.

As you might know, getting tensorflow to work on the M1 chip is a bit messy but I managed to do it following this tutorial: https://github.com/mrdbourke/m1-machine-learning-test

Now, I have an environment named `tensorflow-test` with python 3.8 and tensorflow correctly installed (I can import it without errors).

Within this environment, I want to build some command lines using click package. I used to have everything integrated beautifully until, for some weird reason, I messed up with the environment and now I can't figure out what is going on.

A simple code to reproduce what I have is the following. Within the tensorflow-test conda environment I have a file with click code `hello.py`:

```
import click
import tensorflow


@click.command()
@click.option('--count', default=1, help='Number of greetings.')
@click.option('--name', prompt='Your name',
              help='The person to greet.')
def cli(count, name):
    """Simple program that greets NAME for a total of COUNT times."""
    for x in range(count):
        click.echo("Hello {name}!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

and another with the set up, `setup.py` :

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="hello",
    version='0.1',
    py_modules=['hello'],
    author='xxx',
    install_requires=[
        'Click',
        'pandas',
        'tensorflow',
    ],
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
         hello=hello:cli
    ''',
   
)
```

When I run it using `python hello.py` everything seems to be working fine. However, when I try to integrate this to be run directly as a command line, I do

`pip install --editable .`

and the following error appears:

```
Requirement already satisfied: Click in ./env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from hello==0.1) (8.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in ./env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from hello==0.1) (1.4.2)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from hello) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I checked and there is a folder named tensorflow in ./env/lib/python3.8/site-packages.

What is going on? Why can't I use hello directly as a command when everything seems to be working fine otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I got it to work now but it is till unclear to me what is the exact reason.

I managed to retrieve the old environment file and I realised that within `$HOME/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages` some files related to tensorboard were missing.

My hunch is that these are the ones beeing installed under the tensorflow dependencies in the link above `conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps`

The weird thing is that when running this command it produces an error so the only way to make it work is to copy paste them from my previous environment...

I will update if I manage to figure out more things.

EDIT: I am now experiencing issues with installation of new packages.

For instance, when using `pip install pyautogui` everything is satisfied but when trying to import it within the environment this appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/luisignaciomenendezgarcia/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyautogui/_pyautogui_osx.py", line 5, in <module>
    import Quartz
  File "/Users/luisignaciomenendezgarcia/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Quartz/__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
    _load()
  File "/Users/luisignaciomenendezgarcia/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Quartz/__init__.py", line 28, in _load
    from Quartz import CoreGraphics as m
  File "/Users/luisignaciomenendezgarcia/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Quartz/CoreGraphics/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from Quartz.CoreGraphics._inlines import _inline_list_
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/luisignaciomenendezgarcia/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Quartz/CoreGraphics/_inlines.abi3.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/luisignaciomenendezgarcia/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Quartz/CoreGraphics/_inlines.abi3.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/local/lib/_inlines.abi3.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/_inlines.abi3.so' (no such file)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/luisignaciomenendezgarcia/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 166, in <module>
    from . import _pyautogui_osx as platformModule
  File "/Users/luisignaciomenendezgarcia/tensorflow-test/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyautogui/_pyautogui_osx.py", line 7, in <module>
    assert False, "You must first install pyobjc-core and pyobjc: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html"
AssertionError: You must first install pyobjc-core and pyobjc: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html
```

Exactly the same occurs with the module keyboard.

There is no problem if I mode out of the environment though.